# How can I make conky run on boot?

Tags: boot, startup, conky

I would like to set conky as a start-up application so I do not have to run `conky` in the terminal after every boot. My conky is based of a template I found on reddit and I have edited it. It can be found below:

```
# conky configuration
##############################################
# Settings
##############################################
background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont Liberation Sans:size=9
xftalpha 1
update_interval 0.5
update_interval_on_battery 1
total_run_times 0
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type normal
##############################################
## cairo-compmgr
own_window_argb_visual yes
##############################################
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
maximum_width 270
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color ffffff
default_shade_color 000000
default_outline_color 828282
alignment top_left
gap_x 12
gap_y 10
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 4
override_utf8_locale no

##############################################
# colors

color1 FFFFFF
color2 FFA500

##############################################
#  Output
##############################################

TEXT
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}SYSTEM ${hr 2}
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}HOST:$alignr$nodename
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}KERNEL:$alignr$kernel
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}UPTIME:$alignr$uptime_short
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}BATTERY:${alignr}${battery_percent}%
${battery_bar}

${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}PROCESSOR ${hr 2}

CPU TOTAL: ${cpu cpu0}% ${cpubar cpu0}
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}${cpugraph cpu0 20,270 FFFF00 FF0000}

CORE 1: ${cpu cpu1}% ${cpubar cpu1}
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}${cpugraph cpu1 20,270 FFFF00 FF0000}

CORE 2: ${cpu cpu2}% ${cpubar cpu2}
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}${cpugraph cpu2 20,270 FFFF00 FF0000}

${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}MEMORY ${hr 2}
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}RAM $alignc $mem / $memmax $alignr $memperc%
$membar
SWAP $alignc ${swap} / ${swapmax} $alignr ${swapperc}%
${swapbar}

${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}STORAGE ${hr 2}
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}/ $alignc ${fs_used /} / ${fs_size /} $alignr
${fs_bar /}
${font sans-serif:normal:size=8}/home $alignc ${fs_used /home} / ${fs_size /home} $alignr
${fs_bar /home}

${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}TOP PROCESSES ${hr 2}
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}NAME${alignc}   PID${alignr}${alignr}% MEM
${font sans-serif:normal:size=7}${top_mem name 1}${alignc}${top_mem pid 1}${alignr}${top mem 1}%
${top_mem name 2}${alignc}${top_mem pid 2}${alignr}${top mem 2}%
${top_mem name 3}${alignc}${top_mem pid 3}${alignr}${top mem 3}%
${top_mem name 4}${alignc}${top_mem pid 4}${alignr}${top mem 4}%
#${top_mem name 5}${alignc}${top_mem pid 5}${alignr}${top mem 5}%
#${top_mem name 6}${alignc}${top_mem pid 6}${alignr}${top mem 6}%
#${top_mem name 7}${alignc}${top_mem pid 7}${alignr}${top mem 7}%

${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}NETWORK${font sans-serif:normal:size=8} (${addr wlan0}) ${hr 2}
Signal: $alignr ${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan0}%
${downspeedgraph wlan0 20,270 00FF00 0000FF -l}
Download: ${downspeed wlan0} $alignr Total: ${totaldown wlan0}
${upspeedgraph wlan0 20,270 5F00FF FF0044 -l}
Upload: ${upspeed wlan0} $alignr Total: ${totalup wlan0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In system settings, choose Applications
2. Click on startup tab
3. In the left bottom corner you will see a '+' button, click it
4. You will find a box to type in a custom command, type in the conky there.